# Confused about Usage of LabelFor() html helper in MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

I am working on an MVC 2.0 C# web Applciation. In one of my form, i am using LabelFor() html helper.

I am using the following syntax:

```
 <%=Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Addedon)%>
```

Here, for this label i would like to associate a initial value that is `DateTime.Now`

I tried some thing like this:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Addedon,new{value=DateTime.Now})%>
```

But, i am getting an error saying that there is no over load for this helper taking two arguments.Please help

**UPDATED:**

The form is create form/ add form which makes an insert operation. So, i am building a model and updating that model to the database.

In that model, i have a field called createdby. So, i need to associate this value with the username logged in and  doing the insert operation.

So, how to associate this username value with the model field and i need to display as label so that it will be read only field.

Hope this makes clear..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LabelFor` is only for, you guessed it, rendering a `<label>` element.
It also uses the `[Display]` and `[DisplayName]` attributes, so you can have a strongly-typed label with custom name.

What you're after is probably this:

```
<div>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addeon) %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Addeon) %>
</div>
```

So the `LabelFor` will generate the property name description (e.g. 'Addeon'), while the `DisplayFor` will render the property value. `DisplayFor` can use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute if you need custom formatting. You can set the default property value in the view model's constructor:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "My awesome date")]
    public DateTime Addeon {get;set;}

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Addeon = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

Actually, your edit would make for a good second question instead of putting it here. Anyway, in your situation I'd create a dedicated view model that would hold the properties you need (e.g. user name) and would be filled in controller. Everything else would be conceptually the same - view would bind to the view model.

Comment: @Patryk..Thanks Is it not possible with out using View Model? I am using only models and no view models any where..

Comment: @Avinash You're already using some kind of model, since you're using strongly typed version of `LabelFor`. That means you have to pass something to the view and mark it as a `model`. :) Anyway, using strongly-typed view models is a *good practice*, so there... If you're not using models, you're giving up a lot of convenience that comes with ASP MVC.

Comment: ..I am strongly binding this view with a model but not view model.

Comment: @Avinash Then you can use the model, it doesn't matter right now if you're using full model or a custom view model. You can use the attributes on the model as well.

Comment: @patryk..i understood now..but what if i want to initialize a label on aspx page not in the model? Is there any way to do it. I am asking this because , i need to initialize a label with the user name logged in..in this case how to handle?

Comment: @Avinash If you just want to display the user's name in a label, you can do `<label> Model.UserName </label>`, or wrap it in a `<div>` etc. That's why using dedicated view models, where you can pass any data you need to the view, is a good solution.